# htaccess URL routing for PHP MVC?

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-routing

I've been searching and have yet to find an article to help me. I'm very unfamiliar when it comes to the rewrite engine of htaccess files, and am currently developing a php mvc framework.

Basically, from the root of the webserver, I need all page requests with their controllers / actions in the url to redirect to App/index.php

So, for example site.com/Login/ would direct to the index.php, and the uri would obviously be parsed out with php to enact the login controller with passed post data.

Comment: You could just look it up in one of the 250 other "MVC" frameworks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mod-Rewrite or PHP router?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1868154/mod-rewrite-or-php-router)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the 'usual' way is to forward all requests for non-existent files and directories to your controller:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ App/index.php [L]
```

Comment: This does not work, I am getting a 403 error. My topmost htaccess file is setup as follows:

Comment: RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ App/index.php [L]