# rewrite ?id=__ to page title stored in db row

Tags: php, mysql, .htaccess, content-management-system, url-rewriting

Thanks in advance for any help.

I am trying to figure out how to rewrite dynamic urls created with a simple cms programming I am building.  The code outputs the URL with the ID (www.mysite.com/index.php?id=1).  I would like to modify the code so that it outputs the title of the row in the db with the id of 1 such as www.mysite.com/home or www.mysite.com/about where about is the title stored in the row of the db with an id of 1.

Here is an example of how the code outputs:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT id, title FROM pages");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    // Do not list the home page twice
    if ($row['id'] != $homeID) {
        $pageID = $row['id'];
        $pageTitle = $row['title'];

        echo "<li><a href='" . BASE_URL . "/index.php?id=$pageID'>$pageTitle</a></li>";
    }
```

I am going off of the CMS tutorial from: http://fwebde.com/web-design/creating-a-php-cms-part-1/

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  I have attempted numerous .htaccess rewrites and NONE of them have worked.  Please let me know if this is as simple as switching around the MySQL code.

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is? Are you having an error? If you're executing the above code when the document loads you can just put $pageTitle in <title> </title> and it will display.

Comment: Whats your problem .. please explain in detail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to modify the line that generates the links then:

```
echo "<li><a href='" . BASE_URL . "/index.php?id=$pageID'>$pageTitle</a></li>";
```

You can either add the title as separate and unused `&title=` parameter, which is a nice hack to avoid having to modify anything else:

```
echo "<li><a href='" . BASE_URL . "/index.php?id=$pageID&title=$pageTitle'>$pageTitle</a></li>";
```

Or generate `123+title` links:

```
echo "<li><a href='" . BASE_URL . "/index.php?id=$pageID+$pageTitle'>$pageTitle</a></li>";
```

This would require to adapt the actual "cms" dispatcher code, because it has to break up the id and the title from the $_GET parameter.

Or even replace the whole `index.php?id=` with just the title:

```
echo "<li><a href='" . BASE_URL . "/$pageTitle'>$pageTitle</a></li>";
```

Which in turn would require to deploy a `.htaccess` rule (something like [htaccess URL routing for PHP MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7693788/htaccess-url-routing-for-php-mvc)). And you would have to modify the `index.php` script again to look up the `id` from `title`. Which again would only work if the titles in your database were all unique.

P.S.: You should actually also use `urlencode($pageTitle)`. And `htmlspecialchars()` on the `$pageTitle` that becomes the link text.

Comment: Your solution was simple for adding the &title=$pageTitle to the link generator part.  I was able to build the .htaccess rewrite and correct that and remove the id=__ portion to just leave the $pageTitle.  It's the simplest things you overlook sometimes :)  Thanks!!!

Comment: Another question, do you know how to adjust the .htaccess to allow for any range of id number?  Such as ?id=1 all the way up to triple digits i.e. ?id=999?  This is what I have so far, sorry for commenting twice.
RewriteRule ^([^_]*)$ /goober/?id=1&title=$1 [L], I would like the ?id=__ portion to allow for any range of id numbers all the way up to 999.  Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Don't strip the `id=???` then. If you just fixate it to `1`, then that's the problem. Without knowing your current incoming URL, I can't fix your RewriteRule.

Comment: the incomiing URL is: http://www.mysite.com/folder/?id=(any number)&linklabel=index  Any help with doing the.htaccess or slug so that the url looks like mysite.com/index, this is what i'm after.  Thanks!

Comment: See the linked link again: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7693788/htaccess-url-routing-for-php-mvc

Answer (score 0):

It wont be as easy as you would like. The simplest way would be to include the page number in your final url. `http://www.mysite.com/1/articles` but I don't know if that would be exactly what you are looking for.

The rewrite rule would be.

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9]*)/.*$ index.php?id=$1
```

What I have done on my own CMS systems is to add another field to the pages table called `urlname`. This would be what the URL would be to access that page. You would need to change all the references to $_GET['id'].

**Add this to functions.php.**

```
function thisPageId(){
    $sql="SELECT id FROM pages WHERE urlname = '" . $_GET['urlname'] ."'";
    $result=mysql_query($sql);
    $row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    return $row['id'];
}
```

**htaccess rewrite rule**

This will redirect any request that does not exist to index.php?urlname=...

```
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) index.php?urlname=$1
```

Replace any references to $_GET['id'] with the value from thisPageId. For your listPages function and anywhere else that the url is displayed, you'll do something like this.

```
echo "<li><a href='" . BASE_URL . "/" . $row['urlname'] . "'>$pageTitle</a></li>";
```

Remember you'll also have to edit your administration pages to add the new field.

Comment: Please please please don't encourage use of unsanitized globals in queries. This is wide open to injection attacks.

Comment: I have another question focusing on the .htaccess portion. RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^_]*)$ /sitefoldernamehere/?id=1&title=$1 [L]

How do I tell the RewriteRule to recognize ANY id number, whether it be 1, 2 or 25 or 100?