# htaccess to remove .php and rewrite url issues

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

So if I have the following url:

```
www.mydomain.com/parser.php?id=19127axbj1
```

how can I use htcaccess to make it as

```
www.mydomain.com/19127axbj1
```

is this possible? I see dribble has `http://drbl.in/caYS`, so was wondering on something like that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mod-Rewrite or PHP router?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1868154/mod-rewrite-or-php-router)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible.

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /parser.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Comment: how about if it's the other way around, what if I do www.mydomain.com/19127axbj1 and this gets translated to the php

Answer (score 0):

Oftentimes, the RewriteRules will say "send requests to this other file, if the requested file does not exist." Example:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /parser.php [L]
```

You would then find the originally requested path with... `$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']`?

This prevents things like recursive requests, and allows you to have "pretty" URLs without breaking all direct file access.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this rule:

```
RewriteRule .* /parser.php?id=$0
```

to change "www.example.com/whatever" to "www.example.com/parser.php?id=whatever"

However, this still allows you to visit "/parser.php" directly without the illusion of the masked URL.  In order to avoid this, you have to redirect with php code:

```
if (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], "parser.php") !== false) {
   header("Location: /$_REQUEST[id]", true, 303);
   exit;
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't this recurse to infinity?
/asd -> /parser.php?id=asd -> /parser.php?id=parser.php?id=asd

Comment: @OhCaN I haven't tried it out so I don't know, but if you write it correctly, Apache will not update the REQUEST_URI so it won't redirect again.